# React JS Form button calling

Tags: reactjs

I am try trying to submit the form once the button is clicked, but the function is not triggering in React.

The only enquiry is on the submit button onclick=submitform.

So I can get the value and update it to the json arry

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Createcomponent extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state={
      firstname:"",
      lastname:"",
      phonenumber:""
    }

    this.ontextchange=this.ontextchange.bind(this)
    this.submitform=this.submitform.bind(this)

  }


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component Mounted");
  }

  ontextchange(event) {
    if(event.target.id==='fname') {
      this.setState({firstname: event.target.value}) 
    }

  }

  submitform() {
    alert("trigger");
    //console.log(this.state)
  }


  render(){ 
    return (

      <div>

        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" onChange={this.ontextchange} value={this.state.firstname} name="fname"/><br/>

        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" onChange={this.ontextchange} value={this.state.lastname} name="lname"/><br/>

        <label for="lname">PhoneNumber:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" onChange={this.ontextchange} value={this.state.phonenumber} name="lname"/><br/>

        <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
        <button onClick={this.submitform}>Submit</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Createcomponent
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. What does the error console say?

Answer (score 0):

You have two "Submit" buttons. Clicking the right "Submit" button triggers the alert correctly using your code as it is.

The left "Submit" button, which is setup as a form submit by setting `type = submit`, doesn't do anything because there actually is no `<form>` in use. Setting up a form as I've added it to your code below, the left "Submit" button works too. I've also created this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-submit-yclt3g) for demonstration.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Createcomponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      phonenumber: ""
    };

    this.ontextchange = this.ontextchange.bind(this);
    this.submitform = this.submitFormButton.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component Mounted");
  }

  ontextchange(event) {
    if (event.target.id === "fname") {
      this.setState({ firstname: event.target.value });
    }
  }

  submitFormButton() {
    alert("trigger");
    //console.log(this.state)
  }

  submitFormOnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("trigger");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submitFormOnSubmit}>
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="fname"
          onChange={this.ontextchange}
          value={this.state.firstname}
          name="fname"
        />
        <br />

        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="lname"
          onChange={this.ontextchange}
          value={this.state.lastname}
          name="lname"
        />
        <br />

        <label for="lname">PhoneNumber:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="phone"
          onChange={this.ontextchange}
          value={this.state.phonenumber}
          name="lname"
        />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <button onClick={this.submitFormButton}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Createcomponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `htmlFor` instead of `for` in React on your label element.